# C# How can I convert an excel cells address in the following notation: "LetterNumber" to "Number, Number" and vice-versa?

Tags: c#, excel, data-conversion

How can I convert an excel cells address in the following notation: "LetterNumber" to "Number, Number" and vice-versa?

Comment: Have you attempted to solve this? What issues did you encounter? What is not working as expected?

Comment: I'm trying to set the value of Worksheet.Cells[] but it does not except the "B3" kinds of values, I am new to c#, so i don't know where to look for answers

Comment: What are you using to interact with Excel? Interop, EPPlus, OpenXML, NPOI...? Because usually there is a method that accepts "B3" format. Also, you don't want to convert to a string `"1,1"` the method accepts two integers, one for row, another for column numbers

Comment: @Magnetron I'm using interop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to set the value of Worksheet.Cells[] but it does not except the "B3" kinds of values

[`Worksheet.Range`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.range.aspx) does:

```
Worksheet.Range("A4").Value = "Foo";
```

I would also advise you not to set one cell at a time if you can help it. Every call to `Cells` or `Range` in a slow interop call, so you'll get much better performance if you put your values in an array and set the value of an entire range in one shot:

```
int[,] values;
// fill values with integers
Worksheet.Range("A1","D4") = values;
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, even if the question wasn't clear, here is an answer for:

> How can I convert an excel cells address in the following notation: "LetterNumber" to "Number, Number" and vice-versa?

```
private const string ALPHABET = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

public static string ToExcelCoordinates(string coordinates)
{
    string first = coordinates.Substring(0, coordinates.IndexOf(','));
    int i = int.Parse(first);
    string second = coordinates.Substring(first.Length + 1);

    string str = string.Empty;
    while (i > 0)
    {
        str = ALPHABET[(i - 1) % 26] + str;
        i /= 26;
    }

    return str + second;
}

public static string ToNumericCoordinates(string coordinates)
{
    string first = string.Empty;
    string second = string.Empty;

    CharEnumerator ce = coordinates.GetEnumerator();
    while (ce.MoveNext())
        if (char.IsLetter(ce.Current))
            first += ce.Current;
        else
            second += ce.Current;

    int i = 0;
    ce = first.GetEnumerator();
    while (ce.MoveNext())
        i = (26 * i) + ALPHABET.IndexOf(ce.Current) + 1;

    string str = i.ToString();
    return str + "," + second;
}
```

**The results are:**

> "1,1" -> "A1"
>   "A1" -> "1,1"
>   "42,231" -> "AP231"
>   "AP231" -> "42,231"

Answer (score 0):

Maxime's ToExcelCoordinates algorithm is not correct.
Excel column number 52 performs "BZ" but it must be "AZ".
The issue concerns all column numbers that are multiple of 26.
A verified solution is:

```
      public static string ToExcelColumnAddress(int columnNr)
      {
         string excelColumnAddress = string.Empty;
         int current = columnNr - 1;
         do
         {
            if (excelColumnAddress.Length > 0)
            {
               current--;
            }
            int index = current % 26;
            char ch = (char)('A' + index);
            excelColumnAddress = ch + excelColumnAddress;
            current = current / 26;
         }
         while (current > 0);
         return excelColumnAddress;
      }
```